# Links seem Truncated when querying href tag with WebBrowser control and VB.Net

Tags: html, vb.net, google-chrome, tags

I have developed a simple application in VB.net that just opens a website, navigates to a certain link in that website and then depending on certain events navigates to another link.

Everything is working fine, except that when I grab the contents of the "href" tag, it seems truncated (for want of a better word). If I inspect the tag in chrome inspector the link is complete, but in my app it is not.

I am using the standard WebBrowser control in VB.Net. But I have tried the WebKit and Awesomium options as well. I must be missing something simple here. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Below is the code I use to grab the "href" tag:

```
        Dim div2 As HtmlElement = WebBrowser4.Document.GetElementById("ctr1")
    'On Error Resume Next
    For Each element As HtmlElement In div2.Document.Links
        TextBox2.Text = "Navigating Web 3 Again " & element.GetAttribute("href") 'TextBox2.Text & element.GetAttribute("href") & vbCrLf
        'element.InvokeMember("Click")
        WebBrowser3.Navigate(element.GetAttribute("href"))

        Exit For
    Next
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using the grab the href tag?

Comment: @RussAwesome Thanks, I have edited my question to include the code I use.